# Can't Find hex Value from X64dbg in hex editor

Tags: patch-reversing

I want to make a simple patcher for exe , so here is the original hex value from the x64dbg before any modify :
[image]

I took the hex value and searched for it in the hex editor ,but can't find any .

So why is that ?

Note: the app is vmprotect

Regards

Comment: Maybe because it's vmprotect and the .text section is packed? have you read packers theory? these are basic features see that if you really want to do this patch you should do it after the vmprotect packer loader finishes and of course patch the crc validation too.

Comment: if you accept, I can share some resources for you to study about it, just ask and I'll attach them with the answer.